# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while populating data in javafx table

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I am a newbie in Hibernate and JavaFX. Here I am trying to view my data in a table from a POJO class using hibernate. but whenever I run my code it shows following error.Exception in Application start method

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native       Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown  Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/workspace_eclipse/PreBiziPos/bin/com/pos/bizipos/controller/CompanyInfoSearch.fxml

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.pos.bizipos.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:409)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
at com.pos.bizipos.controller.CompanyInfoSearchController.getInfo(CompanyInfoSearchController.java:106)
at com.pos.bizipos.controller.CompanyInfoSearchController.initialize(CompanyInfoSearchController.java:95)
```

Here is my pojo class BPG_COMPANY_INFO.java

```
package com.pos.bizipos.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class BPG_COMPANY_INFO implements Serializable{
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_company_id", strategy = "com.pos.bizipos.CompanyIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_company_id")  
@Column(length=11)
private String Company_Id;

@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Name;
@Column(length=100)
private String Country_Name;
@Column(length=10)
private int Post_Code;
@Lob
private String Company_Adress;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Email;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Web;
private int Company_Phone;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Division;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_District;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Police_Station;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_Upazilla;
@Column(length=100)
private String Company_City;


//For all tables the following fields are common
@Column(length=1)
private int Active_Status;
@Lob
private String Remarks;
@Column(length=12)
private int Entered_By;
private Date Entry_Timestap;
@Column(length=12)
private int Updated_By;
private Date Update_Timestap;
@Column(length=500)
private String Flex1;
@Column(length=12)
private String Flex2;
@Column(length=12)
private String Flex3;
@Column(length=12)
private String Flex4;
@Column(length=12)
private String Flex5;









 public String getCompany_City() {
    return Company_City;
 }

public void setCompany_City(String company_City) {
    Company_City = company_City;
}

public int getActive_Status() {
    return Active_Status;
}

public void setActive_Status(int active_Status) {
    Active_Status = active_Status;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return Remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    Remarks = remarks;
}

public int getEntered_By() {
    return Entered_By;
}

public void setEntered_By(int entered_By) {
    Entered_By = entered_By;
}

public Date getEntry_Timestap() {
    return Entry_Timestap;
}

public void setEntry_Timestap(Date entry_Timestap) {
    Entry_Timestap = entry_Timestap;
}

public int getUpdated_By() {
    return Updated_By;
}

public void setUpdated_By(int updated_By) {
    Updated_By = updated_By;
}

public Date getUpdate_Timestap() {
    return Update_Timestap;
}

public void setUpdate_Timestap(Date update_Timestap) {
    Update_Timestap = update_Timestap;
}

public String getFlex1() {
    return Flex1;
}

public void setFlex1(String flex1) {
    Flex1 = flex1;
}

public String getFlex2() {
    return Flex2;
}

public void setFlex2(String flex2) {
    Flex2 = flex2;
}

public String getFlex3() {
    return Flex3;
}

public void setFlex3(String flex3) {
    Flex3 = flex3;
}

public String getFlex4() {
    return Flex4;
}

public void setFlex4(String flex4) {
    Flex4 = flex4;
}

public String getFlex5() {
    return Flex5;
}

public void setFlex5(String flex5) {
    Flex5 = flex5;
}

public String getCompany_Division() {
    return Company_Division;
}

public void setCompany_Division(String company_Division) {
    Company_Division = company_Division;
}

public String getCompany_District() {
    return Company_District;
}

public void setCompany_District(String company_District) {
    Company_District = company_District;
}



public String getCompany_Police_Station() {
    return Company_Police_Station;
}

public void setCompany_Police_Station(String company_Police_Station) {
    Company_Police_Station = company_Police_Station;
}

public String getCompany_Upazilla() {
    return Company_Upazilla;
}

public void setCompany_Upazilla(String company_Upazilla) {
    Company_Upazilla = company_Upazilla;
}

public BPG_COMPANY_INFO() {

}

  public BPG_COMPANY_INFO(String id,String name,String country,int postcode,String adress,String email,String web,int phone,String div,String dist,String upazilla,String pstation) {
    this.Company_Id=id;
    this.Company_Name=name;
    this.Country_Name=country;
    this.Post_Code=postcode;
    this.Company_Adress=adress;
    this.Company_Email=email;
    this.Company_Web=web;
    this.Company_Phone=phone;
    this.Company_Division=div;
    this.Company_District=dist;
    this.Company_Upazilla=upazilla;
    this.Company_Police_Station=pstation;
}
 public BPG_COMPANY_INFO(String name,String country,int postcode,String adress,String email,String web,int phone,String div,String dist,String upazilla,String pstation) {

this.Company_Name=name;
this.Country_Name=country;
this.Post_Code=postcode;
this.Company_Adress=adress;
this.Company_Email=email;
this.Company_Web=web;
this.Company_Phone=phone;
this.Company_Division=div;
this.Company_District=dist;
this.Company_Upazilla=upazilla;
this.Company_Police_Station=pstation;
}



public String getCompany_Id() {
return Company_Id;
}

public void setCompany_Id(String company_Id) {
Company_Id = company_Id;
 }

public String getCompany_Name() {
    return Company_Name;
}
public void setCompany_Name(String company_Name) {
    Company_Name = company_Name;
}
public String getCountry_Name() {
    return Country_Name;
}
public void setCountry_Name(String country_Name) {
    Country_Name = country_Name;
}
public int getPost_Code() {
    return Post_Code;
}
public void setPost_Code(int post_Code) {
    Post_Code = post_Code;
}
public String getCompany_Adress() {
    return Company_Adress;
}
public void setCompany_Adress(String company_Adress) {
    Company_Adress = company_Adress;
}
public String getCompany_Email() {
    return Company_Email;
}
public void setCompany_Email(String company_Email) {
    Company_Email = company_Email;
}
public String getCompany_Web() {
    return Company_Web;
}
public void setCompany_Web(String company_Web) {
    Company_Web = company_Web;
}
public int getCompany_Phone() {
    return Company_Phone;
}
public void setCompany_Phone(int company_Phone) {
    Company_Phone = company_Phone;
}
 }
```

Here is my CompanyInfoSearch.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.pos.bizipos.controller.CompanyInfoSearchController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="46.0" layoutY="148.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="680.0" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Company Details">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button fx:id="back_button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Back">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="Show_button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="col_id" prefWidth="40.0" text="ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="col_name" prefWidth="57.0" text="Name" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_country" prefWidth="71.0" text="Country" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_division" prefWidth="55.0" text="Division" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_city" prefWidth="62.0" text="City" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_distict" prefWidth="62.0" text="District" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_upazilla" prefWidth="68.0" text="Upazilla" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_pstation" maxWidth="500.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Police Station" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_post" prefWidth="72.0" text="Postcode" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_mail" prefWidth="61.0" text="Mail" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_web" prefWidth="68.0" text="Web" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="col_phone" prefWidth="89.0" text="Phone" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my controller class

```
package com.pos.bizipos.controller;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;

import com.pos.bizipos.HibernateUtil;
import com.pos.bizipos.entity.BPG_COMPANY_INFO;
import com.pos.bizipos.interfaces.CompanyInterface;
import com.pos.bizipos.model.BPG_COMPANY_INFOmodel;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class CompanyInfoSearchController implements Initializable,CompanyInterface {




        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_id;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_upazilla;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_web;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_name;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_distict;

        @FXML
        private Button back_button;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_pstation;

        @FXML
        private Button Show_button;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_division;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_city;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_mail;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String> col_country;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, Integer> col_post;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, Integer> col_phone;

        @FXML
        private TableView<BPG_COMPANY_INFO> table;

        private BPG_COMPANY_INFOmodel model;
        private Session session;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Id"));
             col_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Name"));
             col_country.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Country"));
             col_division.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Division"));
             col_distict.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_District"));
             col_mail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Mail"));
             col_web.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Web"));
             col_phone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, Integer>("Company_Phone"));
             col_pstation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Police_Station"));
             col_post.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, Integer>("Company_Post_Code"));
             col_upazilla.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_Upazilla"));
             col_city.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BPG_COMPANY_INFO, String>("Company_City"));
             table.setItems(getInfo());

        }
        private ObservableList<BPG_COMPANY_INFO> getInfo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              ObservableList<BPG_COMPANY_INFO> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                List<BPG_COMPANY_INFO> company = session.createQuery("from BPG_COMPANY_INFO").list();
                session.beginTransaction().commit();
                company.stream().forEach(list::add);

                return list;
        }


    }
```

Here is my MainApp.java

```
package com.pos.bizipos;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    private double xOffset=0;
    private double yOffset=0;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {


            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/pos/bizipos/controller/CompanyInfoSearch.fxml"));
            root.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            });
      /*      root.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                window.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                window.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            });*/
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            window.setTitle("BiziPOS:: Version 1.0");
         //   window.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/logo.png"));
          //  window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();



    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        if(HibernateUtil.setSessionFactory())
        launch(args);
        else
        {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("An error has occured!");
                alert.setHeaderText("Database Connection Error!");
                alert.setContentText("Please contact the developer");
                alert.showAndWait();
                Platform.exit();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active` you are starting two Hibernate transactions, one when loading the FXML as it seems.

Comment: also note that the Platform.runlater in your main will not work: it's available only if the fx-application thread is started (which is done during launch)

Comment: Can you suggest where should I change @M. le Rutte

Comment: I am not an Hibernate expert, but I am pretty sure you should debug your `getInfo()` method after having read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction())

Comment: By adding rollback() in a try catch block resolved my problem. Thanks a lot @M.leRutte